# Preventing Error 2501

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I have created a form that on the click of a command button creates and email and sends the email. But when the email page come up and the user exits out of the email without sending it an error 2501 pops up. Does anybody know how to prevent this error by just popping up a message box informing the user the email was cancelled?

Thanks in advance

This is what I have so far:

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# and DiscoverTime= '" & Me!DiscoverTime & "' and TailNumber= '" & Me!TailNumber & "' and FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "Email", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"

DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
End If

errhandle:
If Err.Number <> 2501 Then
MsgBox ("Email Cancelled")
DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the reverse logic. The error thrown is 2051, so you should check for that error not <>. Also please use the full code, that way it is easier to give the right solution. Here is the modified code that would work.

```
On Error GoTo errhandle
    'Your If is missing here. 
        Me.Filter = "CurrentDate= #" & Format(Me!CurrentDate, "yyyy\-mm\-dd") & "# and DiscoverTime= '" & _
                    Me!DiscoverTime & "' and TailNumber= '" & Me!TailNumber & "' and FleetID= '" & Me!FleetID & "'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
        DoCmd.SendObject acSendForm, "frmETIC", acFormatPDF, "some.email@domain.com", "", "", "Recovery Report", "Attached is the submitted Recovery Report"

        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
    End If

exitErr:
    Exit Sub
errhandle:
    If Err.Number = 2501 Then
        MsgBox ("Email Cancelled")
        DoCmd.Close acForm, "frmETIC", acSaveNo
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmETIC", acNormal, , , acFormEdit, acWindowNormal
    Else
        MsgBox "Error (" & Err.Number & ") - " & Err.Description & " Occurred."
    End If
    Resume exitErr
```

Comment: Can you do me a favor and take that email out of the code you posted though... :/ so sorry

Comment: Done ! Sorry took a while, I am on holiday. Lol.